# How to add 0 to month that are not listed in the array?

Tags: php

I made a query from which I get result containing total and the date in Y-m format.

This is what I will get from the query.

```
$targets = array(
            array(
                "total" => 239,
                "date_result" => "2018-10"
            ),
            array(
                "total" => 269,
                "date_result" => "2018-11"
            ),
            array(
                "total" => 169,
                "date_result" => "2018-12"
            ),
            array(
                "total" => 169,
                "date_result" => "2019-01"
            )
        );
```

Here I have data available until 2019-01 but I need to display 0.0 for month not available in above array result. So what I did is get the number of months first.

```
   for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $pastSixMonths[] = date("Y-m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
    }
```

Then, I try following code:

```
foreach($pastSixMonths as $month) {
            foreach($targets as $target) {
                if($target["date_result"]  == $month) {
                    array_push($finalArray, array($target["date_result"] => $target["total"]));
                } else {
                    array_push($finalArray, array($target["date_result"] => 0.0));
                }
            }
        }
```

I need result something like:

```
array(
"2019-01" => 169,
"2018-12 => 169
)
```

Comment: `if(array_key_exists($month, $targets))` makes zero sense here, the month values are not the keys of your $target arrays.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to fix this in the place where you get those results “from the query” already. Prepare your array with all the months and values set to 0 first, then loop over the result of your query, and assign the total of the current record to the array element with the matching key.

Comment: @04FS yes I got it.

Comment: @04FS thank you that helped me fix easily

Answer (score 2):

Here your code.

```
$obj = [
  [
    "total" => 239,
    "date_result" => "2018-10"
  ],
  [
    "total" => 269,
    "date_result" => "2018-11"
  ],
  [
    "total" => 169,
    "date_result" => "2018-12"
  ],
  [
    "total" => 169,
    "date_result" => "2019-01"
  ]
];

$new_obj = array_column($obj, "total", "date_result");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $date = date("Y-m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
  if(!isset($new_obj[$date])){
    $new_obj[$date] = '0.0';
  }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_obj);
```